# Tickle / Rubover Custom Gesture Recognition Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uigesturerecognizer

I am trying to set up a custom gesture over an Image in Xcode (Swift).
The gesture is about rubbing the image or tickling it continuously and accordingly firing my function in time interval while the finger is moving.

I would appreciate some help here.

thanks a lot.

Answer (score -1):

//That's my idea, not tested

```
var time = 0.0
var timeInterval = 1.0
var everyTime = 0.1
func addPan() {
    let imageView = UIImageView()
    //imageView.frame = xxxx
    let pan = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(panGesture(gesture:)))
    imageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    imageView.addGestureRecognizer(pan)
}
func panGesture(gesture : UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
    if gesture.state == .changed, time >= timeInterval {
        print("time interval is \(everyTime) every is \(everyTime)")
    }
}
func addtimer() {
    let timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: timeInterval, target: self, selector: #selector(timerAction), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    RunLoop.current.add(timer, forMode: RunLoopMode.commonModes)
}
func timerAction() {
    time += timeInterval
    if time >= timeInterval {
        time = 0.0
    }
}
```